# Only insert SQL records if they do not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, duplicates, sql-insert

I know this question has been asked a few times, but I need an answer more specific to my situation.

I am using PowerShell to insert variables into a table in SQL. The important variable that is being inserted is the name of a folder. I want to be able to insert records only if these folder names are not already present in the SQL table.

When I start the script, it will gather all folder names in the specified location into an array. Right now I have it inserting every folder, but when I run this in the future I want it to only insert the new ones.

**For example:**

Say I have these 5 Folders:

- C:\Users\User.Name\2015-01-01
- C:\Users\User.Name\2015-02-01
- C:\Users\User.Name\2015-03-01
- C:\Users\User.Name\2015-04-01
- C:\Users\User.Name\2015-05-01

Let's say that 2015-01-01, 2015-02-01, and 2015-03-01 are already in the table. The array that I gather in PowerShell will have all 5 folders inside.

*I only used 5 folders as an example, when in reality I need to do this for about 100 folders, so this is not something that I can hard code for each folder.*

How can I insert only 2015-04-01 and 2015-05-01 into the table? Is this something that would need to be done at the SQL level, or something more complex with my PowerShell array?

Here is how I gather my array in PowerShell:

```
$Location = 'C:\Users\User.Name'

$FolderArray = gci -Path $Location | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '2015*' } | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
```

Here is what the SQL looks like:

```
Foreach ($i in $FolderArray) 
{
    $sql ="INSERT INTO Database.dbo.Table ([Location]) VALUES ('" + $i + "');"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this on the SQL level.

```
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT `Location` FROM Database.dbo.Table WHERE `Location`= '2015-01-01')
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO Database.dbo.Table ([Location]) VALUES ('2015-01-01');
END
```

Comment: so if I replace 2015-01-01 with the variable for the PowerShell array, this should work then?

Comment: Should do, probably best to try it in a temporary table first juts incase. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single query (no `if`):

```
INSERT INTO Database.dbo.Table([Location])
    SELECT location
    FROM (VALUES('2015-01-01')) as l(location)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Database.dbo.Table t WHERE t.location = l.location);
```

With this structure you can even construct the query to include all values at the same time.

However you do the update, you should have a unique index/contract on `table(location)`, so the database ensures uniqueness.  Then if you insert them one at a time, you can include code to catch errors and ignore duplicate key errors.